# Converting simple date/time string in moment.js doesn't detect AM/PM

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to convert a simple string to a unix timestamp using moment.js

```
moment('2014-01-14 07:25 PM').unix();
moment('2014-01-14 07:25 AM').unix();
```

The problem is I get the same result with AM or PM in that string.

```
1389684300
```

What gives?

Comment: I had the same question but needed to convert to ISO string. The solution by @Pekka worked great for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have been a bug in version 2.0.0. Updating to 2.5.0 and the problem is fixed.

Comment: It's not guaranteed to work everywhere, though. I would use an explicit format string in any case.

Answer (score 6):

The [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/) make no mention that your specified format is guaranteed to be correctly recognized. It says

> Warning: Browser support for this is inconsistent. Because there is no specification on which formats should be supported, what works in some browsers will not work in other browsers.`

You should probably explicitly specify a format in the second argument.

This should work ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pAy2G/)):

```
moment('2014-01-14 07:25 PM', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A').unix();
```

Comment: The comment in the docs "Because there is no specification on which formats should be supported" is no longer correct. ES5 specifies a [version of ISO 8601](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15), though it's not supported everywhere and your advice to provide the format is good.